# Dúvida com dataTable e/ou modelagem JSF/JPA

Tags: java, jsf

Boa noite, estou com o seguinte problema... a princípio parece meio bobo, mas sinceramente não consigo sair dele

quero criar uma tabela onde as colunas são DOMINGO, SEGUNDA, TERÇA, QUARTA, QUINTA, SEXTA, SABADO respectivamente... e nessas colunas sejam mostrados os dados,
esses dados possuem como atributo o dia da semana em questão, qual seria a melhor maneira então de fazer eles aparecerem na tabela na coluna correta...

```
<p:dataTable id="tbl"
    value="#{bean.registros}"
    var="registro" emptyMessage="Nenhum registro">

<p:column headerText="DOMINGO">

         </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="TERÇA-FEIRA">

         </p:column>

     <p:column headerText="QUARTA-FEIRA">

         </p:column>


e assim vai...
```

vejam, cada registro contido na lista "registros" possui um atríbuto chamado dia, que é um enum com o dia da semana respectivo, persistir, editar etc tudo está funcionando normalmente, o problema é que não sei como fazer para que os registros que contenham o dia = SEGUNDAFEIRA apareçam apenas na coluna correta...

em outras palavras tenho uma lista de objetos para ser mostrada em um data table onde em cada coluna devem ficar listados os objetos que possuem um atributo x (um enum que representa o dia da semana)

Tentei fazer uma lógica com o rendered, mas além de achar que foi "gambiarra" demais, não ficou bom, causando diversos outros problemas...

Alguém com alguma boa idéia ?

Comment: Me parece que você está usando a abordagem errada. Criar sete colunas, cada uma para um dia da semana me soa muito estranho. Eu criaria uma tabela `DIA_DA_SEMANA` com os sete dias e faria um relacionamento N-N de sua tabela de registros com a tabela de dias da semana.

Comment: Boa noite @Victor, obrigado pela resposta mas não consegui compreender, teria como me explicar um pouco esse raciocínio ?

Comment: Ah, desculpe. Quem entendeu errado fui eu. Quando você se refere a "tabela" eu estava pensando em tabela no banco de dados, e não em tabela no JSF ou no HTML.

Answer (score 1):

O problema da sua abordagem é que você não tem uma estrutura de dados adequada ao componente JSF.

Explico. No seu sistema podem haver 2 itens na segunda, 1 na terça e 3 na quarta, correto? Isso funciona numa tabela comum, mas um componente `DataTable` representa o que costumamos chamar de "grid", ou seja, uma lista de registros com um número definido de linhas, cada uma representando um registro do sistema. Não dá para ter 3 itens numa coluna e dois na outra.

Dá pra fazer algum tipo de gambiarra usando `DataTable`, mas outras opções que devem ser consideradas de acordo com seu problema são:

- [DataList](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataList.xhtml): coloque 7 listas uma ao lado da outra, pois nela você consegue exibir 7 listas independentes. Você vai precisar dividir lista original por dia.
- [Schedule](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml): se sua ideia for algum tipo de calendário, use este componente para facilitar bastante a exibição dos eventos. Use a visualização *Weekly*, isto é, semanal.

Se ainda assim preferir usar o `DataTable`, vai precisar transformar sua estrutura de dados, mais ou menos assim:

1. Crie um POJO com um atributo para cada coluna do tipo registro. Exemplo:

   ```
   class DataTableBean {
       Registro domingo, segunda, terca, quarta, quinta, sexta, sabado;
       ...
       //getters e setters
   }
   ```
2. Divida sua lista de registros original em 7 diferentes listas, uma para cada dia da semana.
3. Crie uma nova lista da classe `DataTableBean`
4. Cria uma nova instância de `DataTableBean`, remova um item de cada lista individual e preenche os registros de cada dia da semana.
5. Repita o passo 4 até não sobrar mais nenhum registro nas listas individuais.

Answer (score 0):

Se você deseja uma marcação de item por linha, como em uma tabela da Zebrinha (http://www.donosdecasa.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/zebrinha.jpg) a forma mais simples e fácil é com o `rendered`, pois um `dataTable` realiza uma iteração de um for na lista e o `rendered` verificaria se o objeto do Enum pode ser apresentado naquela coluna.

Caso você deseja que apareçam todos os registros "preenchendo" todas as colunas de uma linha conforme o enum `DiaDaSemana` de cada registro, a melhor forma seria criar uma classe que representasse cada linha e realizar esse populate de classes no seu `ManagedBean`, antes de enviar para a página Xhtml.

Por fim, você poderia observar o `subtable` do `primefaces` (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/subTable.xhtml) para ver se tem algo que possa ajudar.